# How to fill empty cells of a column with random values based on standard deviation BUT every cell MUST contain new value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill empty cells from a single column (and then from multiple columns) using the standard deviation. I have seen several explanations but so far haven't seen any that is straightforward and pertinent to this question. Thank you in advance for your time!

Here is what I have so far:

To obtain random values, I first calculated the mean for the Math column:

```
filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'exam.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(filename)

math_mean = data['Math'].mean()
print(math_mean)
```

The output of that is `73.625`

Then, I calculated the Standard deviation:

```
math_std = data['Math'].std()
print(math_std)
```

Which gave me `10.14097064951308` for STD.

```
73-10 = 63
73+10 = 83
```

Based on the calculation above, I need to generate random values between 63 and 83 and fill in the empty cells of the Math column. I used `np.random.randint()` to get the random values:

```
random_grades = np.random.randint(63,83)
print(random_grades)
```

So everything is fine so far, and the random values do get inserted into the empty cells. However, it's the same value repeating over and over.

I'm using this syntax:

```
#Producing random age values
random_grades = np.random.randint(63.48, 83.76)
print(random_grades)

#Storing new random ages to variable
new_grades = data.Math.fillna(random_grades)
print(new_grades)

#Passing new values to table
data['Math'].fillna(new_grades,inplace=True)
print(data)
```

This is the output:

```
0     79.0
1     82.0
2     85.0
3     77.0 # random value
4     70.0
5     77.0 # same random value
6     84.0
7     67.0
8     77.0 # same random value
9     63.0
10    59.0
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: @Shaido Thank you, Shaido. It kinda sorta answers it but not really. Raymond Toh answered it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert values into empty cell, use `fillna` function.

Example to fill values into columns History:

```
df.History = df.History.fillna(new_values)
```

Comment: Awesome. It worked! Can I bother you with one more question? How can I do it for all columns?

Comment: @RobinSage if you want to apply to all columns,
  df = df.fillna(new_values)